# se salta la linea en el base de datos con el uso tres checkbox con el bucle foreach

Tags: php, html, mysqli, formularios

hola tengo un formulario 
perdonadad voy ha editar la pregunta se me ha olvidado el codigo de mandar el formulario con metho POST: este el codigo

```html
<form action="boletin.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-check mb-6 mr-sm-2">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="desratizar[]" value="desratización">                                                          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">                                      
 desratización
</label> 
</div>
<div class="form-check mb-6 mr-sm-2">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="desinsectar[]"  value="desinsectacion">
<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
          Desinsectación
 </label>
</div>
    <div class="form-check mb-6 mr-sm-2">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="desinfectar[]" value="desinfeccion">
<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
 Desinfección
 </label>
 </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill" name="hacer_boletin" placeholder="enviar">
                            </form>
```

```html
<?php 
include ('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['hacer_boletin'])){

    $desratizar =$_POST['desratizar'];
    $desinsectar = $_POST['desinsectar'];
    $desinfectar = $_POST['desinfectar'];  
      
    foreach($desratizar as $llave => $valor){

        $guardar ="INSERT INTO boletines set desratizacion='$valor'";
       
        $resultado= mysqli_query($conn, $guardar);
    }

   
    foreach ($desinsectar as $llave => $valor) {

        $guardar = "INSERT INTO boletines set desinsectacion='$valor'";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $guardar);
    }

      
    foreach ($desinfectar as $llave => $valor) {

        $guardar = "INSERT INTO boletines set desinfeccion='$valor'";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $guardar);
    }
     
    
  



}

?>
```

el problemas cuando le los tres clip  el formulario  lo manda a la base de dato pero no me da ningun erro pero el problema es que en la base de datos mysql  se me salta las linea como la imagen de abajo que en vez de una sola linea se me salta la siguiente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
se podria hacer de otra forma para que solo en caso de que el usario diera los tres se guardara en una sola linea

Comment: Si, es solo un problema de logica, lo que no entiendo es el foreach, puede venir mas de un valor en cada checkbox?

Comment: como se podria hacer para que insertara y guardara en la base de datos sin que saltara una linea

Comment: tenes dos opciones, un solo insert (vos estas haciendo 3 inserts) o un insert y luego un update a ese mismo registro. Estas usando un for each para ver si viene un valor?

Comment: el foreach solo usa un array ¿No podra usar 3 o mas array a la vez ? por eso lo separo para q lellera los array  y asi guardara en un la base de dato

Comment: lo he intentado hacer de otras forma  y me pone como "on" es decir como boleano

Comment: @gbianchi hola ya creo q lo he solucionado

Comment: Agrega una solucion a tu pregunta. Igual no queda muy claro porque no querrias que fuera booleano.. Ese campo deberia ser booleano en la DB

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi es que me he encasillado en el foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola intenta insertar todo en una sola consulta

```
insert into boletines(desratizacion,desinsectacion,desinfeccion) values ('$desratizar ','$desinsectar','$desinfectar')
```

Y también elimina los [] en tus nombre de formulario para que no llegue como arreglo

por ejemplo:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="desinsectar"  value="desinsectacion">
```

O también puedes dejarlos pero que todos tu check tengan el mismo nombre algo asi

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="check[]"  value="desinsectacion">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="check[]" value="desratización">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="check[]" value="desinfeccion">
```

y en la parte de php haces lo siguiente

```
$checks=$_POST['check'];
insert into boletines(desratizacion,desinsectacion,desinfeccion) values ('$checks[1]','$checks[0]','$checks[2]')
```

Answer (score 0):

en el codigo php  he echo esto

```
<?php 
include ('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['hacer_boletin'])){

    $desratizar =$_POST['desratizar'];
    $desinsectar = $_POST['desinsectar'];
    $desinfectar = $_POST['desinfectar'];  



        $guardar ="INSERT INTO boletines set desratizacion='$desratizar',desinsectacion='$desinsectar',desinfeccion='$desinfectar'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $guardar);







}

?>
```

y en los actributos  value de checkboss he puesto los variables